# Noob question -> how can I get a wall of html tags in Reactjs without it returning "[Object object]"?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to display "x" number of h2 tags back at the browser,but it comes back rendering at the screen "x" numbers of  "[Object object]".

If I declare with "",it doesnt render as a tag,but simple text.
I do realize I can try it with an array,but I just would like to know why it doenst work and if theres a way to achieve it in the most simplest way possible

```
import React from 'react';

function App(){
  var n1 = <h2>testing</h2>
  var n2;
  for(let i = 0;i<10;i++){
    n2 = n2 + n1;
    console.log(n2)
  }
  return <>{n2}</>
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n2 = n2 + n1;
```

The issue is here - you can't add objects together so JS will try to add them as if they were numbers. Since that's not the case, the objects will be converted to strings and concatenated. The default toString value for objects is [object Object] so that's what you're seeing displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Without quotes around, this isn't text, it's `JSX`, which React compiles into this function: `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`, which returns a new React element object, so it won't work to console log that.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Since it is an object, you can list out the properties of that object by trying `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`. But a React element itself is not an HTML element until it gets rendered with `React.render()`, so it's not going to show as HTML tag in the console, it's just a javascript object at this point.

Comment: thank you,im going to take a look at this

Answer (score 0):

I think react will only let you display an array of nodes
Not appended nodes with '+'
Try this:

```
var n2 = []

n2.push(n1)
```

Also n1 is already scoped and I'm not sure it can be re-referenced multiple times in a render. Try and move it into the loop's block scope

```
  var n2 = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<10;i++){
      var n1 = <h2>testing</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** simply add a component to another using `+` operator. Actually every variable or object can hold only one jsx component as its value.
Simplest way as you mentioned is the use of arrays:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App(){
  var n1 = <h2>testing</h2>
  var n2 = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<10;i++){
    n2.push(n1);
    console.log(n2)
  }
  return <>{n2}</>
}

export default App;
```

a simpler way of doing that is this, might be helpful:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
const App = () => <>{ Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => <h2>testing</h2>) }</>;
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.I just tried with array as mentioned by Daniel and it works if I stick to it.But thanks again